# the mysql variable returns null when executing query

Tags: mysql, null

Hi this is my query..

```
SELECT u.url,u.url_id,@mailid=wu.email FROM urls_uptime_log u INNER JOIN website_suburls wd ON u.url_id=wd.id
 INNER JOIN website_to_sms wu ON wd.websiteId=wu.website_id WHERE  u.time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND u.status<>200
```

**EDIT**:
the output table i got is:(this output contains the site's url with status!=200)

```
url     |  url_id    |@mailid=wc.email
+-------+------------+----------------
http:/dfg   1616          aaa@gmail.com
+--------+------------+----------------
http:dfff   1621           aaa@gmail.com
+--------+------------+----------------
http:dfff   1619           bbb@ymail.com
```

i need to find how many sites of a particular email is checked? can i use the below query?

```
SELECT COUNT(u.url) FROM urls_uptime_log u INNER JOIN website_suburls wd ON u.url_id=wd.id 
INNER JOIN website_to_sms wu ON wd.websiteId=wu.website_id WHERE wu.email=@mailid
```

Comment: Looks like you've muddled some syntax. I think you want `wu.email as mailid` instead of `@mailid=wu.email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a value to a user variable you have to use assignment operator `:=` instead of comparison operator `=`. If you actually meant it try

```
SELECT u.url,u.url_id, @mailid := wu.email 
  FROM urls_uptime_log u JOIN website_suburls wd 
    ON u.url_id = wd.id JOIN website_to_sms wu 
    ON wd.websiteId = wu.website_id 
 WHERE u.time_stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND u.status <> 200
```

On the other hand if you just wanted to give an alternative name (an alias) to a column do

```
SELECT u.url, u.url_id, wu.email mailid ...
```

**UPDATE:** It's hard to tell without seeing your table schemas, sample data and desired output but you can try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.url) 
  FROM urls_uptime_log u JOIN website_suburls wd 
    ON u.url_id = wd.id JOIN website_to_sms wu 
    ON wd.websiteId = wu.website_id
 WHERE wu.email IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT wu.email 
      FROM urls_uptime_log u JOIN website_suburls wd 
        ON u.url_id = wd.id JOIN website_to_sms wu 
        ON wd.websiteId = wu.website_id 
     WHERE u.time_stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
       AND u.status <> 200
)
```

Comment: one more doubt how can i print that @mailid in php?? can i use echo??

Comment: It depends on what you really meant by doing it. Did you really want to use variables in a query or you just wanted to rename a column? User variables in this form are usually used to sequentially process data while it's being retrieved (e.g. to overcome some MySQL limitations) like accessing a value of previous row...

Comment: i need to use that mailid on the second query which i want to execute after the above query

Comment: Then it looks like you don't need MySQL variables. You can either use the second approach to rename a column or just don't do anything at all. You'll have in your resultset a column named `email` and retrieve it's value(s) to a variable of any name in your client code and use it as a parameter to your second query

Comment: @user007 See updated answer for a possible solution. If it it's not what you need than consider to provide table schemas, sample data and desired output.

Comment: its didn't work as i want sir..but no worry... i had did tht using views..any ways thanks for ur help sir.. is there any problem in using views in the project?? i mean anything related to efficiency etc.

Comment: @user007 There is absolutely nothing wrong with using views. And again if you need help then just post schemas, sample data and expected output.